# Smart card reader on Fedora 33 / loading specific driver for usb device

Tags: usb, drivers, fedora, smartcard

recently we got smart cards and readers to be able to connect to VPN with Cisco AnyConnect. Readers are Identiv SCR3500 A. When plugged in system recognizes this correctly in opensc-tool -l. However any operation related to the card fails with Unsupported card message (for example opensc-tool -r 0 -n) or messages like
`Slot 0 (0x0): (GetSlotInfo failed, CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED)` in pkcs11-tool for example.

This leads to the idea of wrong driver being used. Identiv does have their own driver on their website [here](https://support.identiv.com/smartfold-scr3500/) but after following the steps nothing changes (it's deploying `libscmccid.so.5.0.35` into pcsc structure : `/usr/local/pcsc/drivers/scmccid.bundle/Contents/Linux`

I tried linking it into libraries or adding the card certificate manually to nssdb with modutil pointing directly to the driver using -libfile parameter but that doesn't work either.

Anyone has idea how to proceed here?

Comment: Seems like the Fedora driver _should_ work.  You have installed `pcsc-lite`, `pcsc-lite-libs`, and `pcsc-lit-ccid`?  Does `lsusb -v -d 04E6:` different significantly from https://ccid.apdu.fr/ccid/readers/Identiv_SCR3500_A_Contact_Reader.txt?

Comment: On some lines i am getting Couldn't open device, some information will be missing but i would say most of them are the same between the txt file and lsusb output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that these card are issued by someone and they work on Windows.

If `opensc-tool` returned an Unsupported card message, the reader is not likely the problem, it is the card. OpenSC supports a number of cards, but not all.
You can see the list of drivers `opensc-tool -D` You can also get the ATR of the card using `opennsc-tool -a`. If it can read the ATR, go to: https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/ and past in the ATR to get more information about the card.

For more info:     https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki
and mailing lists: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Mailing-lists

Comment: Thanks this is good info. No idea if issuer uses Windows.I could get ATR from opensc-tool -a and website says it's Axalto Cryptoflex .NET or Gemalto IDPrime v2+ .NET . When checking against http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/smartcard_list.txt it's Gemalto one there. These should be all supported. Then all the errors are a bit puzzling.